# Pandas read csv with multiple whitespaces and parse dates

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas

I have a csv file that looks like

```
Year Mo Da (01,52) 
1950  1    1    0.00    
1950  1    2    0.00    
1950  1    3    0.05    
1950  1    4    0.00    
1950  1    5    0.07    
1950  1    6    0.07
```

and I would like transform it into a dataframe with 2 columns: a datetime column of YYYYMMDD (using the "Year", "Mo", and "Da" columns in the raw data) and then the rainfall at the grid point (e.g. 01, 52) as the second column.

A desired output would be:

```
Datetime Rainfall
19500101 0.00
19500102 0.00
19500103 0.05
```

I am stuck on two issues: appropriately accounting for the whitespace during the read-in and properly using `parse_dates`.

The simple read-in command:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_fl)
```

Almost correctly reads in the headers, but splits the (01,52) into separate columns, yielding a trailing NaN, which shouldn't be there.

```
     Year Mo Da (01  52)
0  1950  1    1    0.00  NaN
```

And trying to parse the dates using

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_fl, parse_dates={'Datetime':[0,1,2]}, index_col=0)
```

leads to an IndexError

```
    colnames.append(str(columns[c]))
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass params `delim_whitespace=True` and pass the 3 columns in a list to `parse_dates` the last step is just to overwrite the column names:

```
In [96]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""Year Mo Da (01,52) 
1950  1    1    0.00    
1950  1    2    0.00    
1950  1    3    0.05    
1950  1    4    0.00    
1950  1    5    0.07    
1950  1    6    0.07"""
df =pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=[['Year','Mo','Da']])
df.columns = ['Datetime', 'Rainfall']
df

Out[96]:
    Datetime  Rainfall
0 1950-01-01      0.00
1 1950-01-02      0.00
2 1950-01-03      0.05
3 1950-01-04      0.00
4 1950-01-05      0.07
5 1950-01-06      0.07
```

So I expect: `df = pd.read_csv(csv_fl, delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=[['Year','Mo','Da']])`

should work followed by overwriting the column names

Comment: Terrific, thank you. I will accept the answer when allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = "..."
>>> pd.read_csv(filename, 
                sep=" ", 
                skipinitialspace=True, 
                parse_dates={'Datetime': [0, 1, 2]}, 
                usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3], 
                names=["Y", "M", "D", "Rainfall"], 
                skiprows=1)
    Datetime  Rainfall
0 1950-01-01      0.00
1 1950-01-02      0.00
2 1950-01-03      0.05
3 1950-01-04      0.00
4 1950-01-05      0.07
5 1950-01-06      0.07
```